# Value in pandas dataframe is 13 but not always recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on an assignment for the coursera Introduction to Data Science course. I have a dataframe with 'Country' as the index and 'Rank" as one of the columns. When I try to reduce the data frame only to include the rows with countries in rank 1-15, the following works but excludes Iran, which is ranked 13.

```
df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
df.loc['Iran', 'Rank'] = 13 #I did this in case there was some sort of 
corruption in the original data
df_top15 = df.where(df.Rank < 16).dropna().copy()   
return df_top15
```

When I try

```
df_top15 = df.where(df.Rank == 12).dropna().copy()
```

I get the row for Spain.

But when I try

```
df_top15 = df.where(df.Rank == 13).dropna().copy()
```

I just get the column headers, no row for Iran.

I also tried

```
df.Rank == 13
```

and got a series with False for all countries but Iran, which was True.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: could you send a link to your dataframe please ?

Comment: instead of df_top15 = df.where(df.Rank < 16).dropna().copy()   did you tried df_top15 = df[df.Rank < 16].dropna() ?

Comment: Thank you, Charles R. I tried your suggestion but still had the same problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to send a link to the dataframe. It is based on reading excel and csv files that are housed on the Coursera system. I have downloaded the files but am not sure how to put them somewhere where they can be publicly accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Italy', 5],
                   ['Iran', 13],
                   ['Tinbuktu', 20]],
                  columns=['Country', 'Rank'])

res = df.where(df.Rank < 16).dropna()

print(res)

  Country  Rank
0   Italy   5.0
1    Iran  13.0
```

However, I dislike this method because via `mask` the dtype of your `Rank` series becomes `float` due to initial conversion of some values to `NaN`.

A better idea, in my opinion, is to use `query` or `loc`. Using either method obviates the need for `dropna`:

```
res = df.query('Rank < 16')
res = df.loc[df['Rank'] < 16]

print(res)

  Country  Rank
0   Italy     5
1    Iran    13
```

Comment: Thank you very much, jpp! Both of your examples solved the problem for me, and yes, it was ugly that the ints were turning to floats.

Comment: I still wonder why the old code didn't work for me, though, even though I am grateful to learn these new ways to do it.